# Dialogue changes between different edits of Return of the Jedi

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

Trying to settle an argument about dialogue changes between the original theatrical release of Return of The Jedi and the special edition version.

In the special edition version during the climactic attack on the Death Star Wedge Antilles X-wing and the Millennium Falcon approach the main reactor and Wedge expresses surprise at the scale of it. Lando, in the Millennium Falcon then instructs him to "go for the power regulator on the north side".

My question is has a line of dialogue been excised? Was there dialogue to the effect of...

Wedge "look at the size of that thing? My proton torpedo's won't even dent it!"
Lando "I'm carrying concussion grenades. You go for the power regulator on the north side".

I am aware dialogue to this effect was included in the comic book tie in of the film but would like to confirm if it did (or did not) ever appear on film. Hope some one out there can help.

Comment: Note that the comics had to be in production before the film was out (I don't recall it being released notably after the film was); they may have included dialog that was in the original script, but was not included (or was modified) in the actual release version. the same would be true of the novel adaptation; if someone has access to that, they might see if it's included there.

Comment: This  is also in the Kahn novelization ("missiles", not "grenades", and slightly different word order, but  extremely close).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As someone who has seen (I believe) every version of this film, with the exception of the original cinema showing I can state that as far as I am aware I have never heard this line be said in any of the films, dialogue during this scene is very limited.

the following link seems to show a pretty complete list of all the different variations :)

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_changes_in_Star_Wars_re-releases

Hope this is useful

Comment: Yup. I never heard that either. And I am a huge jerk about Lucas changing things from the original release.

Answer (score 0):

You've conflated two different movies.

Wedge's line: "Look at the size of that thing!" is from **Episode IV: A New Hope**

(in this clip, you barely hear Red Leader's response: "cut the chatter")

Comment: Just to add a little context this was one of those late friday night ever so slightly drunk situations. I was pretty sure the dialogue was not spoken but could not say for certain. Since asking the question I've managed to get hold of the Special edition DVD that also included the theatrical cut on the second disk. The dialogue does not appear in either version so i think we can say case closed! Thank you all!

Comment: ...right @dominicfonde - a portion of the dialogue you thought you remembered is actually in a *different movie* - the dialogue exists, just not where you thought it did.

Comment: As a subquestion (perhaps I should log it as a new question?) can anyone confirm if the dialogue I mentioned appears in either the novelisation or comic adaptation of the film? It would be good to know if my memory is still playing tricks on me.